# Floating li into a grid pattern leaves undesired spacing

Tags: html, css, layout, html-lists, floating

At the very high level, this is my HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item1</li>
  <li>Item2</li>
  ...
  <li>Item21</li>
</ul>
```

and this is my CSS:

```
li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0.3em;
  padding: 2px;
  max-width: 10em;
  min-width: 10em;
  min-height: 12em;
  border: 1px solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
  background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
}
```

My intention is to arrange the list items into a 3x7 grid pattern, but what actually happens is this: The first six items display exactly as I want them to, in a 3x2 grid. The seventh, however, displays on a row on itself, floating all the way to the right of the container div, with the rest of the "row" blank. Then the pattern continues on the next line. [Here's a picture of what it looks like](http://imageshack.us/a/img688/9953/10995065.png)

My list has exactly 14 items, so I can confirm that this pattern repeats at least once more. My question is if anyone can tell me why only the 7th item behaves this way, and what I could do to fix it.

Comment: Where's the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/5v4Bm/1/show/

Comment: You should include the whole CSS since when the provided code is put in a HTML file, it works fine. So it's likely that other styles are affecting it.

Comment: I think it may just be in my browser styles, but I'm not sure what would be causing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason your fifth item is 1px higher than the others in the screenshot you provided. This is what causes the seventh item to behave like it does. Take a look at your code again and see if you do anything to the fifth item that causes it to be higher than the others.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing, but I'll take a closer look - thanks!